# Drawing a UIImageView at position of user tap

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, touch

This is the 2nd time I have asked this.  How do I draw an image at the location of the user's tap every time the user taps the screen?

Could you please leave a sample project or code because I am new to iPhone programming and have a hard time understanding certain methods etc.
Thanks,
Tate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't move my character!  Please HELP!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977225/cant-move-my-character-please-help)

Comment: In fact, dupe of two of the poster's other questions as well: [making a uiimageview appear when screen is tapped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970671/making-a-uiimageview-appear-when-screen-is-tapped) and [making images appear how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970293/making-images-appear-how)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];

    UIImageView * anImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:anImage];
    [anImageView setCenter:[touch locationInView:self.view]];
    [self.view addSubview:anImageView];
    [anImageView release];
}
```

In the future, read the documentation or use Google.

Comment: Ok thank you so much I'm sorry but I really don't like the documentation.  Again thank you.
Tate

Comment: Whether or not you like the documentation, you're going to have to use it. You can't always just ask other people to provide you with the code. It might be worth buying one of the many iPhone books or following some online tutorials. Google seems pretty competent at finding stuff.